# 2-morphism between circuits in a monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, 2-categories

We are used to seeing equations between circuits in monoidal categories [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqXyN.png)

I am wondering about morphisms between string diagrams.  I think they are 2-cells.  [I found an example of a 2-cell here, but it is for just a standard composition of morphisms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx4P9.png).

What I am wondering about is 2-cells between arbitrary string diagrams in a monoidal category.  Are there examples?  Is it modelled with surface diagrams?  Can FD-Hilb be seen as a 2-category, and if so, what are the 2-cells?

[I asked this over at math stack but got no real response.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277836/2-morphism-between-circuits-in-a-monoidal-category)